# issue in webform module of drupal 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am using drupal web form module . the form is added in block . but when i resize the window the text fields do not change. the size remains same , i have edited to change label and submit image but unable to change text fields here is my css

```
input.webform-calendar {
    display: none;
    padding: 3px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
html.js input.webform-calendar {
    display: inline;
}
.webform-container-inline label {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.webform-container-inline div, .webform-container-inline div.form-item {
    display: inline;
}
.webform-container-inline div.description {
    display: block;
}
.webform-container-inline div.messages {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.webform-container-inline div.ajax-progress-bar div {
    display: inherit;
}
.webform-client-form #edit-submit {
    background: url("../images/submit.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    width: 35%;
}
.form-textarea-wrapper textarea {
    width: 58%;
}
```

Comment: Depends on your theme dude, you could have anything going on!

Comment: @Alex i have added in form in a block theme. and included this block in template

Comment: You should be able to use 'web developer tools' in your browser to determine where a style rule is affecting the form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set a width of the form...

```
.form-notice form {
   width: 60%;
}
```

Then set your form elements to the following...

```
.form-notice .form-text,
.form-notice .form-textarea {
   width: 100%;
}
```

This way the form elements will fit whatever the size the form has resized to.